# Protect and unprotect memory safely for threading where it is only unprotected for required action

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

So I have loaded a key for encrption as a `byte[]` and want to use `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedMemory` as an added layer of security on the loaded key. The idea was to have an object that would store and provide the key privately and wrap an Action with `ProtectedMemory.Protect` and `ProtectedMemory.Unprotect` so that when the Action finishes the key is protected again. The problem is that I wasn't thinking about threading at the time and ran into a bug where two threads accessed the key provider at the same time, calling Protect or Unprotect twice in a row causing the key to be incorrect for the second thread.

I don't want to lock the key provider object (currently serving it up as a singleton) as that means only one thing can be encrypted at a time which could potentially slow things down a lot. Instead I want to leave the key unprotected until the last Action is executed, and if no current Actions are running then protect the key.

I was able to resolve the bug using some static class's methods and counters to keep track of if the key was being used but I am worried that it isn't thread safe. I've tried to search for this problem but I lack the right terms to get a hit.

Here is the original code I want to make safe:

```
public class KeyProvider : IKeyProvider
{
    private readonly byte[] _key;

    // when created store as a single static object by a factory
    // because we don't need to keep loading the key each time 
    // from the config
    public KeyProvider()
    {
        _key = ConfigObject.LoadKey();
    }

    // I want to make this thread safe
    public T UseKey<T>(Func<byte[], T> action)
    {
        try
        {
            ProtectedMemory.Unprotect(_key, MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon);
            // I should probally copy the key so that the action 
            // can't accidently modify the source key to prevent
            // data coruption
            T value = action(_key);
            return value;
        }
        finally
        {
            ProtectedMemory.Protect(_key, MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon);
        }
    }
}

// simple example usage of the UseKey method
public class Encryptornator
{
    private readonly IKeyProvider keyProvider;
    private readonly IEncrypt encrypt;
    public Encryptornator(IKeyProvider keyProvider, IEncrypt encrypt)
    {
        this.keyProvider = keyProvider;
        this.encrypt = encrypt;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(string value)
    {
        // key is protected
        return keyProvider.UseKey((key) => {
            // key is unprotected
            return encrypt.Protect(value, key);
        });
        // key is protected
    }
}
```